# I am getting an exception error when running the my ASP.NET web application,

Tags: exception, model-view-controller

I am getting an exception error when running the my ASP.NET web application. I think it has to due my an enum by I am not sure. I have done some research on "Value cannot be null" and "Parameter name: source" exceptions, just don't understand some of the solutions presented and not sure if they directly apply to my issue.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please 
    review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error:

Line 8:      <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
Line 9:      <div>
Line 10:         There are @Model.Count() restaurants in the db.
Line 11:     </div>
Line 12:    

Source File: C:\Users\cef19\source\repos\OdeToFood\OdeToFood.Web\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 10

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +4960432
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\cef19\source\repos\OdeToFood\OdeToFood.Web\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +73
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9847873
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163


________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4210.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi this is additional information to help address my issue. Thanks Chris

**********************************************************************
Here is my Controller:

using OdeToFood.Data.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OdeToFood.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        IRestaurantData db;

        public HomeController()
        {
            db = new InMemoryRestaurantData();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.GetAll();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}


****************************************************************
Here are my Models: 
CuisineType.cs Model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OdeToFood.Data.Models
{
    public enum CuisineType
    {
        None,
        Italian,
        Indian,
        French

    }
}

****************************************************
Here is my Restaurant.cs Model:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OdeToFood.Data.Models
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public CuisineType Cuisine { get; set; }
    }
}

****************************************************
Here is my Class from my Services folder named InMemoryRestaurantData.cs

using OdeToFood.Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace OdeToFood.Data.Services
{
    public class InMemoryRestaurantData : IRestaurantData
    {
        List<Restaurant> restaurants;

        public InMemoryRestaurantData()
        {
            restaurants = new List<Restaurant>()
            {
                new Restaurant { ID = 1, Name="Scott's Pizza", Cuisine= CuisineType.Italian},
                new Restaurant { ID = 2, Name="Tersiguels", Cuisine= CuisineType.French},
                new Restaurant { ID = 3, Name="Mango Grove", Cuisine= CuisineType.Indian},

            };
        }
        public IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetAll()
        {
            return restaurants.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
        }
    }
}

********************************************
Here is my class from my Services Folder named IRestaurantData.cs

using OdeToFood.Data.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OdeToFood.Data.Services
{
    public interface IRestaurantData
    {
        IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetAll();
    }
}

***************************************
Here is my Index View



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <div>
        There are @Enumerable.Count(Model) restaurants in the db.
    </div>
   
</div>

*********************************************************
Hi I figured out the issue. I needed to have the model inside of my parentheses. See code  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.GetAll();
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Hi I figured out the issue. I  needed to have the model inside of my parentheses. See code  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.GetAll();
            return View(model);
        }